# Debian: Mounting NFS Volume at boot with fstab not working, How to change when this is attempted on boot

Tags: debian, mount, nfs, fstab

So there are a bunch of NICs and vlans on the server and after adding the last ones the auto mount of a network volume is not working. I can do it all right if I SSH in and use `mount` however it doesn't happen with `fstab`.

What I'm speculating is the interfaces that are needed to reach the networked storage come up too late, I have no experience with the startup so I have only a few bits of debug you show such as

```
# chkconfig --list
networking                0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on 
nfs-common                0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off  S:on
```

(that's among others, do ask if you need to see other entries, I don't actually know what would be needed)

How can I make the nfs mounting be done at a later point, this above suggests to me that perhaps the nfs stuff happen too early?

```
# ls -lh /etc/rc5.d/
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 677 Mar 27  2012 README
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Apr 10 13:46 S14portmap -> ../init.d/portmap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Apr 10 13:46 S15nfs-common -> ../init.d/nfs-common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Apr 11 11:19 S17fancontrol -> ../init.d/fancontrol
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Apr 10 13:46 S17rsyslog -> ../init.d/rsyslog
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14 Apr 10 15:59 S17sudo -> ../init.d/sudo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Apr 11 11:18 S18apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Apr 11 11:18 S19acpid -> ../init.d/acpid
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Apr 11 11:18 S19atd -> ../init.d/atd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14 Apr 11 11:18 S19cron -> ../init.d/cron
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Apr 11 11:18 S19exim4 -> ../init.d/exim4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 Apr 11 11:18 S19mpt-statusd -> ../init.d/mpt-statusd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Apr 11 11:18 S19nagios3 -> ../init.d/nagios3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Apr 11 20:49 S19postfix -> ../init.d/postfix
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Apr 12 19:15 S19rsync -> ../init.d/rsync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Apr 11 11:18 S19ssh -> ../init.d/ssh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Apr 11 11:18 S21bootlogs -> ../init.d/bootlogs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Apr 11 11:18 S22rc.local -> ../init.d/rc.local
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19 Apr 11 11:18 S22rmnologin -> ../init.d/rmnologin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  23 Apr 11 11:18 S22stop-bootlogd -> ../init.d/stop-bootlogd
```

How can I delay or change the order of events so that it'd mount with `fstab`, what to look for anyway?

Comment: Why is the `networking` service off?  A mechanism should be in place to cause network mounts in fstab to be delayed until the network starts, but it looks like your network isn't started using the standard mechanism, which may cause the other to fail.

Comment: Yeah it's actually a virtual machine on some cloud bullsh*t platform perhaps thats why, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I could work around that by putting the mount command in `rc.local` (also worked as `@reboot root mount -a` in `/etc/crontab`). But if someone has suggestions about fixing it by changing the services startup that'd be nice to know.